# How can I remove double quotes in CDF?

Tags: cdf-format

I wrote a small code and deployed into `CDF`.

```
  CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], Style["This is my name"],WindowSize -> {100, 100}]
```

The `String`(This is my name) shows in double quotes ,whenever we have to open `CDF`.

[image]

How can I remove that double quotes in `CDF`?

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you want to put a naked `Style` exprssion into a .cdf file. I believe a .cdf should built up from `Cell` expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"],
 Style["This is my name", ShowStringCharacters->False],WindowSize -> {100, 100}]
```

or

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"],
   TextCell["This is my name"], WindowSize -> {100, 100}]
```

Comment: +1 For clarifying `ShowStringCharacters` and showing a straightforward use of `TextCell`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to editing notebook cells is:

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], 
Graphics[Text[Style["This is my name"]]], WindowSize -> {100, 100}]
```