# How do I remove Wolfram Branding in a CDF PopupWindow?

Tags: cdfplayer, enterprise-cdf

The answers below show how to remove the Wolfram banner from a CDF. And how to use OutputForm to remove the double quotes from some text in CDFs.

[How do I remove Wolfram Branding in a CDF?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20491/how-do-i-remove-wolfram-branding-in-a-cdf)

[How can I remove double quotes in CDF?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/how-can-i-remove-double-quotes-in-cdf)

However, the Wolfram banner still appears in PopupWindows invoked from within an Enterprise CDF. I tried wrapping the PopuWindow in:

```
SetOptions[PopupWindow[.....],PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"PluginToolbarEnabled" -> False}]
```

A work around for getting all text to appear properly formatted, **including subscripts**, was to generate the content of the CDF as an output cell (which I got from another question a while ago which I can't find right now, sorry):

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[],Next,Cell] then CDFDeploy[file, NotebookSelection[],Method -> 
"Standalone", Deployed -> True, "Target" -> "PlayerPro"]]
```

However, this method unfortunately ignores the option to remove the banner.

(One way to get subscripts to appear in the CDF without the banner is to export the formatted text as a png and include it in a Row statement (!)).

Also, surprisingly, text in popup windows appears ok without wrapping in OutputForm[]).

Is there a way to remove the banner from PopupWindow[]s generated using Enterprise Mathematica?

Comment: Have you tried `PopupWindow[..., PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"PluginToolbarEnabled" -> False}]`? Documentations says any notebook option should work.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba  yes that works! The option gets highlighted red so maybe it is undocumented. I tried earlier to do that but hadn't enabled dynamic in the main window yet; before enabling dynamic the banner was still there, then after enabling dynamic the banner goes away. Running the cdf from a trusted folder the banner appears briefly in the popup window then goes away once the dynamic content is initialized. Please can you put this as an answer? I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A result from a `PopupWindow` is not a `NotebookObject[]` because there isn't any new window till it is clicked. That is why `SetOptions` will not work.

Yet `PopupWindow` accepts all notebooks' options and passes them later to generated windows so the quick fix is:

```
PopupWindow[..., PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"PluginToolbarEnabled" -> False}]
```

#### Licensing

This should work in FreePlayer too but the removal of Wolfram branding elements is against the license. It is allowed in Enterprise generated CDFs though (OP's case).

http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/licensing-options.html

Comment: I found that it only removes the banner if there is some dynamic content in the popup window. Otherwise the banner stays. I just wrapped a constant in dynamic and now that popup also has banner removed. The banner appears momentarily while the content is evaluated, then disappears.